# Can anyone use GetIt! to install any product in Delphi 10.4.1?

Tags: delphi

I have been trying since Friday (Oct 16) for GetIt to install anything, like a component, or anything else for that matter. When I press the Install button for, say "Icons8 1.0", I get an error message:

```
Loading EULAS...
  Cannot load data from the server: "RADSTUDIO.json" metadata file does not exist.
  Setup cannot continue due to corrupted installation file.
```

This error occurs in Delphi 10.4 Update 1, and Delphi 10.3.

Is GetIt working?

Comment: you are not alone , found this question here : https://en.delphipraxis.net/topic/3731-get-it-radstudio-json-metadata-not-found/

Comment: solution  should be here : http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Sydney/en/Release_Notes

Comment: https://www.systemcamp.com/fix-delphi-getit-package-manager-failing/

Comment: Also totally broken here! Nothing helped. The Embarcadero server (open in browser) is also down

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Solution should be :
http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Sydney/en/Release_Notes

> If you use the offline installer, RAD Studio will not be able to access the GetIt Package Manager until you manually switch to "online mode". To do this, we recommend using the GetItCmd.exe tool: `GetItCmd.exe -c=useonline`

Comment: Embarcadero has their ___ so far up their ___  that this is still broken on Alexandria 11.1.

Comment: Looks like they break old installers on purpose after each new release.
https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Sydney/en/Release_Notes -> Error for weeks now

Answer (score 2):

I just have fixed it without getitcmd.
Run [this](https://download.microsoft.com/download/0/6/5/0658B1A7-6D2E-474F-BC2C-D69E5B9E9A68/MicrosoftEasyFix51044.msi) hotfix from MS (from [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/update-to-enable-tls-1-1-and-tls-1-2-as-default-secure-protocols-in-winhttp-in-windows-c4bd73d2-31d7-761e-0178-11268bb10392#easy) at the bottom), and getit-104.embarcadero.com will be available in a minute. It fixes TLC