# Entry point not found on 32 bit C++ builder app

Tags: c++builder, vcl, c++builder-10.4-sydney

I have a VCL project that I'm writing using C++Builder 10.4.1.

So far, the project has 52 modules (cpp/h) and is going to grow. The project does not use any Packages or DLLs other than the built-in ones.

For the 32-bit version, when I do a re-build, it runs just fine, but if I change something and just do a make, I get the error message:

> The procedure entry point _wcscpy could not be located in dynamic link library myAppName.exe

I've also discovered that if I delete `myAppName.ils` before re-making the app, this does not happen.

So, I either gave to do a full re-build, which takes a long time, or I have to remember to delete the stupid `.ils` file, which is annoying.

Does anyone have a better and more permanent solution for this?

By the way, compiling for 64-bit does not have this issue.

Comment: "*..., or I have to remember to delete the stupid `.ils` file, which is annoying*" - you can use a [Pre-build event script](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Build_Events) to automate that.

Comment: Turn off incremental linking

Answer (score 2, accepted):

.ils files are one of the files used to [keep state when incremental linking](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Sydney/en/C%2B%2B_Linker_State_File_(*.ilc,_*.ild,_*.ilf,_*.ilr,_*.ils)). A bug resolved by deleting the .ils file likely indicates a bug in the incremental linker.

To resolve it, you can [disable incremental linking](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Sydney/en/C%2B%2B_Linker#Linking_Options) in Project Options > Building > C++ Linker. You may also want to [file a bug report](https://quality.embarcadero.com/), but please note the linkset (set of object files plus these .il* files) will likely be required to fix it.

As Paul notes, you should also use TwineCompile to decrease build times - that way even if you do a full build it should be much faster. It's free if your update subscription is active. [Info here](https://blogs.embarcadero.com/boost-c-compile-speeds-with-newly-updated-twinecompile-now-in-getit/) including videos showing how to use it. It takes less than a minute to set up.

Comment: It turns out a bug report already existed for this [RSP-16423](https://quality.embarcadero.com/browse/RSP-16423) since 10.1 Berlin but Embarcadero claims they have fixed it in 10.2.2. Somehow the error is back. I've reported it again [RSP-32175](https://quality.embarcadero.com/browse/RSP-32175). Please vote for it.

Answer (score 2):

Tangentially - use the new Twine Compile option to speed your build time.

Comment: I love to be able to do that and even though we do have active subscription, when I try to install it, I get the error message "RADStudio.json" not found.

Comment: I am copying directly from another answer:  (https://stackoverflow.com/a/64448776/8106387)   
---
> Solution should be :  http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Sydney/en/Release_Notes  

> > If you use the offline installer, RAD Studio will not be able to access the GetIt 
> > Package Manager until you manually switch to "online mode". To do this, we 
> > recommend using the GetItCmd.exe tool: GetItCmd.exe -c=useonline